# Как сделать кастомную сортировку только в одной категории каталога?

Tags: wordpress, сортировка, woocommerce

CMS Wordpress + WooCommerce

Делаю кастомную сортировку каталога по определенному атрибуту. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно выводить эту сортировку только в одной определенной категории и ее дочерних категориях?

Прилагаю код с созданием кастомной сортировкой.

```
/* Критерии сортировки с атрибутом */
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args');
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($_GET['orderby'])) {
        switch ($_GET['orderby']) :
            case 'pa_razmer-sazhencza' :
                $args['order'] = 'ASC';
                $args['meta_key'] = 'pa_razmer-sazhencza';
                $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
            break;
        endswitch;
    }
    return $args;
}
 
/*  Добавляем способ сортировки в выпадающий список */
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
 
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['pa_razmer-sazhencza'] = 'По высоте';
    return $sortby;
}
 
/* Сохраняем атрибуты ввиде метаданных*/
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_woocommerce_attr_to_meta' );
function save_woocommerce_attr_to_meta( $post_id ) {
    foreach( $_REQUEST['attribute_names'] as $index => $value ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $value, $_REQUEST['attribute_values'][$index] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При добавлении новой сортировки добавьте условие, вместо `your_parent_cat_slug` - имя своей родительской категории.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');

function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby($sortby)
{

    if (is_product_category("your_parent_cat_slug") || is_nested_product_category("your_parent_cat_slug")) {
        $sortby['pa_razmer-sazhencza'] = 'По высоте';
    }

    return $sortby;
}

function is_nested_product_category($slug_name)
{
    $cat = get_term_by('slug', $slug_name, 'product_cat');

    return term_is_ancestor_of($cat->term_id, get_queried_object_id(), 'product_cat');
}
```